# calling function in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function, activerecord

I try to use a function in Rails but I keep getting the same error. I tried a bit of everything!!

I define the function in my model. It is a big calculation but I completely simplified it too, and still get the same error!!

My function in my model:
Original function:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :partner

  #
  public  
  def find_next_user_value(user_sequence)
   last_user_value = User_Sequences.where(:user_sequence_name=> user_sequence).map{|element| element.last_used }
    user_prefix = User_Sequences.where(:user_sequence_name=> user_sequence).map{|element| element.user_sequence_prefix }
    user_length = User_Sequences.where(:user_sequence_name=> user_sequence).map{|element| element.user_sequence_length }
    User_Sequences.where(:user_sequence_name=> user_sequence).map{|element| element.user_sequence_prefix } + number_to_string(User_Sequences.where(:user_sequence_name=> user_sequence).map{|element| element.last_used } +=1).ljust(User_Sequences.where(:user_sequence_name=> user_sequence).map{|element| element.user_sequence_length } - User_Sequences.where(:user_sequence_name=> user_sequence).map{|element| element.user_sequence_prefix }.bytesize,"0")
  end
end
```

Simplified version:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :partner

  #
  public
  def find_next_user_value
    "TEST2"
  end
end
```

The call from the controller:

```
  def new
   @customer = Customer.new(partner_id: @partner.id, customer_name: @partner.name, partner_number: @partner.number, number: @customer.find_next_user_value("Customer_Number"))
  end
```

simplified:

```
  def new
    @customer = Customer.new(partner_id: @partner.id, customer_name: @partner.name, partner_number: @partner.number, number:  @customer.find_next_user_value)
  end
```

In both case I get the same error:

> undefined method `find_next_user_value' for nil:NilClass

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `@customer.find_next_user_value` before `@customer` is even defined. Did you perhaps mean to define `find_next_user_value` as a class method?

If so, use `def self.method_name(args)`:

```
def self.find_next_user_value
```

And in your controller:

```
Customer.find_next_user_value("Customer_Number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are calling the method even before the customer object is created. So you are not finding that method.

Create an **after_save** call back so that your required number field gets updated after the customer object is created.

```js
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :partner


  after_save :update_number_field

  def update_number_field
   self.number = self.find_next_user_value("Customer_Number")
   self.save
  end

  
  public  
  def find_next_user_value(user_sequence)
   last_user_value = User_Sequences.where(:user_sequence_name=> user_sequence).map{|element| element.last_used }
    user_prefix = User_Sequences.where(:user_sequence_name=> user_sequence).map{|element| element.user_sequence_prefix }
    user_length = User_Sequences.where(:user_sequence_name=> user_sequence).map{|element| element.user_sequence_length }
    User_Sequences.where(:user_sequence_name=> user_sequence).map{|element| element.user_sequence_prefix } + number_to_string(User_Sequences.where(:user_sequence_name=> user_sequence).map{|element| element.last_used } +=1).ljust(User_Sequences.where(:user_sequence_name=> user_sequence).map{|element| element.user_sequence_length } - User_Sequences.where(:user_sequence_name=> user_sequence).map{|element| element.user_sequence_prefix }.bytesize,"0")
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you explain in wordt what that peace of code just does? I am new and still learning.... Thank you!!